# Search array for specific parameter Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array that contains property objects. these objects have a listing number, String first name, and int year.

When I input a random listing number, I want to check the array to see if that listing number exists, then If it does, I want to remove that property

I am not sure how to access the array object to get to the listing number

this is what I have so far

```
public class Property {

//primary fields
private String listingNumber;

}


public Property(String listingNumber) {

    this.listingNumber = listingNumber;

}
```

Class with array

```
private Property[] properties;
```

is called SalesAgent

```
public SalesAgent(String company) {

    this.company = company;

    this.properties = new Property[]{};
}

public void removeProperty(String listingNumber) {

    if(listingNumber != null){

        boolean found = false;
        for(int ndx = 0; ndx < this.properties.length && !found; ndx++) {


            if(getListingNumber() == listingNumber) {

            properties[ndx] = null;
            found = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the stack overflow. Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to ask questions.

Comment: If you want to remove a `Property` from a list, then you need something with variable size. An array has a fixed size, so it's better to use a `List`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove a `Property` from a list, then you need something with variable size. An array has a fixed size, so it's better to use a `List`.

Assuming that `properties` is a `List<Property>`, you can then write somthing like this:

```
int foundIndex = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < properties.size(); i++) {
    if (Objects.equals(properties.get(i).getListingNumber(), listingNumberToFind)) {
        foundIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
if (foundIndex != -1) {
    properties.remove(foundIndex);
}
```

It starts to walk over the list with `Property` objects, and if an object with the listing string is found, then capture its index and stop walking. If such index is found, delete the object with this index from the list.

This can also be achieved with Java 8 streams:

```
properties = properties.stream()
   .filter(p -> !Objects.equals(p.getListingNumber(), listingNumberToFind))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

A few notes:

- `removeProperty` does not belong in the `Property` class. The `Sales` class holds the list with properties, so it should probably reside there.
- You should *always* compare `String`s with the `equals` method. For reference types (which `String` is), `==` compares object identity, rather than their value. I used the static method `Objects.equals`, which uses `equals` under the hood.
- If you lookup such listing number often, you may want to use a `Map`, mapping listing numbers to their corresponding `Property` objects:

  ```
  Map<String, Property> properties = new HashMap<>();
  // Put your values into the map
  properties.put(«listingNumber», «property»);
  ...
  ```

  ```
  properties.remove(listingNumber);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `equals` instead of `==`

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things I wanted to point out in your code.

1. `setListingNumber() == null;` is not the right way to set null value/ remove value in the java. This must be a setter function that accepts an argument. You can pass the argument.
2. You can use the break statement here. If your condition satisfied then you can break the loop and stop loop execution from that step.

   ```
   Class Property { 

     public void removeProperty(String listingNumber) {
        if(listingNumber != null){
            for(int ndx = 0; ndx < this.properties.length; ndx++) {
               if(getListingNumber() == listingNumber) {
                   setListingNumber(null);
                       break;
               }
          }
      }
      public void setListingNumber(String listingNumber){
            this.listingNumber = listingNumber;
      }
   }
   ```